# How to define the response url at OpenIDAuthenticationFilter?

Tags: spring-security

I have a `CustomOpenIDAuthenticationFilter` extends `org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationFilter`. <strike>I want to define the response url after the authentication is successful</strike>, but do not know how to do it. Any help you might have would be very much appreciated.

I have the following code at the moment:

```
public class CustomOpenIDAuthenticationFilter extends OpenIDAuthenticationFilter{
protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("service");

    public CustomOpenIDAuthenticationFilter(){
        super();
        ProxyProperties proxyProps = new ProxyProperties();
        proxyProps.setProxyHostName(PROXYNAME);
        proxyProps.setProxyPort(PROXYPORT);
        HttpClientFactory.setProxyProperties(proxyProps);
    }

    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws AuthenticationException, IOException {   
        //i think the response url should be defined here. 
        Authentication au = super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);     
        return au;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Sorry for your time, i did not explain my problem correctly.
So, when my login page is sending authentication request to openid provider, the request contains a returnToUrl, where is "The URL on the Consumer site where the OpenID Provider will return the user after generating the authentication response. ". On a non-spring application, i would do

```
AuthRequest authRequest = manager.authenticate(discovered, returnToUrl);
```

My question is how could I specify this returnToUrl at my CustomOpenIDAuthenticationFilter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify the returnToUrl you can override the `String buildReturnToUrl(HttpServletRequest request)` method. An example of making this an arbitrary URL is given below:

```
public class CustomOpenIDAuthenticationFilter extends OpenIDAuthenticationFilter {
  ...
  protected String buildReturnToUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // this URL needs to be processed by CustomOpenIDAuthenticationFilter to validate
    // the OpenID response and authenticate the user
    return "https://example.com";    
  }
}
```

As the comment mentions this URL should be a URL that `CustomOpenIDAuthenticationFilter` will process since it is what validates the OpenID response.

Comment: Thanks, Rob. And sorry, i did not explain my problem correctly. Can you have a look at edit part of my problem, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for "this URL should be a URL"

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved by creating a custom filter an place it before OPENID_FILTER

```
    </http>
         ...
         <custom-filter before="OPENID_FILTER" ref="myBeforeOpenIDFilter" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="myBeforeOpenIDFilter"class="com.example.provider.openid.MyBeforeOpenIdFilter" />
```

And below there is my implementation of this custom filter

```
    package com.example.provider.openid;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.Filter;
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    public class MyBeforeOpenIdFilter implements Filter{

static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyBeforeOpenIdFilter.class);

static class FilteredRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    public FilteredRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public java.lang.StringBuffer getRequestURL(){
            String baseUrl = (String) super.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("applicationBaseUrl");
        StringBuffer sb = super.getRequestURL();

        int index = sb.indexOf("/j_spring_openid_security_check");
        if(index != -1){
            // here replace the host etc with proper value
            if(baseUrl.endsWith("/")){
                baseUrl = baseUrl.substring(0, baseUrl.length()-1);
            }
            logger.debug("Changing the getRequestURL to inject the correct host so openid login could work behind proxy");
            logger.debug("Original getRequestURL: "+sb.toString());
            logger.debug("Replacing the baseUrl with: "+baseUrl);
            sb.replace(0, index, baseUrl);
            logger.debug("New getRequestURL: "+sb.toString());
        }
        return sb;
    }

}


@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    //No need to init
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    chain.doFilter(new FilteredRequest((HttpServletRequest) request), response);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    //No need to destroy
}

    }
```

In this way you can define your openid provider using the default namespace 
and have the filter plugin out if you need it. In my implementation I'm taking the baseUrl from the servlet context but it can be simply hardcoded

Hope this will help someone

Cheers 
Szymon